# Effective Redirection Rule For web.config

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, web-config, dotnetnuke, web.config-transform

​I wrote few rules to redirect from few old URLs to one new URL:

```
<rule name="strategies1st" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)URL1" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="URLnew" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="strategies2nd" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="URL2" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="URLnew" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

They work great on the site.

I look for one rule solution for each page group by this logic (|| as or):

```
URL1 || URL2 || URLn --> URLnew
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In DNN, I would do this by creating a list of URLS that a page is supposed to respond for, and setting up the URLs in the TABURLS table, something like

```
INSERT  INTO TabUrls
        ( tabid ,
          seqnum ,
          url ,
          httpstatus ,
          issystem ,
          PortalAliasUsage ,
          CreatedByUserID ,
          CreatedOnDate ,
          LastModifiedByUserID ,
          LastModifiedOnDate
        )
VALUES  ( TABID ,
          1 ,
          '/SomeOldUrl.htm' ,
          301 ,
          1 ,
          0 ,
          1 ,
          GETDATE() ,
          1 ,
          GETDATE()
        );
```